# Panda: How to generate multiple columns in a loop?

Tags: pandas

The below code (calculation of moving average over N-days) works for well. But I want to replace other numbers (e.g., 5, 10, 20, etc.) with 50. Not sure if I can turn the below code into something in for loop. Could anybody please help me?

```
df['ma50pfret']= df['ret']

df.loc[df.adjp >= df.ma50, 'adjp > ma50']= 1
df.loc[df.adjp < df.ma50, 'adjp > ma50']= 0
df.iloc[0, -1]= 1

df['adjp > ma50']= df['adjp > ma50'].astype(int)
df.loc[df['adjp > ma50'].shift(1)== 0, 'ma50pfret']= 1.000079 # 1.02**(1/250)

df['cum_ma50pfret']=df['ma50pfret'].cumprod()
df.head(10)
```

Comment: Are your columns named `ma5`, `ma10`, etc? You could use `for i in [5, 10, 20]: column_name = f"ma{i}"` and perform your calculations within the loop.

Comment: Just use f-string as @gofvonx suggested, like `df[f'adjp > ma{i}']` etc. in a loop.